# Can't start Node js server in the example application of Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I downloaded Angular phonecat example phoject, moved to this directory and tried 'npm start' command. Result:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.17.2/v0.10.32/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.1.4
3 info using node@v0.10.32
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart angular-phonecat@0.0.0
6 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 info angular-phonecat@0.0.0 Failed to exec prestart script
8 verbose stack Error: angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
8 verbose stack Exit status 3
8 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.17.2/v0.10.32/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:212:16)
8 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
8 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
8 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
9 verbose pkgid angular-phonecat@0.0.0
10 verbose cwd /Users/marya/JS:HTML:CSS/angular-phonecat
11 error Darwin 13.4.0
12 error argv "node" "/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.17.2/v0.10.32/bin/npm" "start"
13 error node v0.10.32
14 error npm  v2.1.4
15 error code ELIFECYCLE
16 error angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
16 error Exit status 3
17 error Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script.
17 error This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
17 error not with npm itself.
17 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
17 error     npm install
17 error You can get their info via:
17 error     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
17 error There is likely additional logging output above.
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't understand why but I can't execute server. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before?

Comment: Yes, the same result

Comment: tried `sudo npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems node is installed with version node@v0.10.32

Anyhow, what really happens is that npm looks in your package.json file, and if you have something like

```
"scripts": { "start": "coffee server.coffee" } }
```

then it will do that. If npm can't find your start script, it will not work

try node start using

```
node <name of your node server>.js
```

and error seen in your `angular-phonecat` Try reinstalling it using `npm` command and try.